# Displaying issue in xs devices using bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

In case of XS devices I want to display column B before col A. But the results is very odd. Any idea how to overcome this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-xs-push-12">A</div>
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-8 col-lg-8 col-xs-pull-12">B</div>
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-2 col-lg-2">C</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-xs-push-12">A</div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-8 col-lg-8 col-xs-pull-12">B</div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-2 col-lg-2">C</div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just in case I am asking. Does this is proper with bigger device? because when I check it. Column B doesn't appear

Comment: Yes! column B appears in all devices when PUSH/PULL is not using there.